# Echo page path suffix only - not the title, path or permalink

Tags: pages, paths

Is it possible to echo a page path suffix only? ie: if the path/permalink is example.com/about, echo just "about"?

My page paths are different than my page titles (ie: page title for example.com/about is "About ACME Co.") so I cannot use [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

I am trying to echo just the suffix so it is the same name as an icon image for each page, so if the page is "about", the icon is `icon_page-about.png`, like this (wpse_page_suffix is where I need the help):

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_img/icon_page-<?php wpse_page_suffix();?>.png" alt="Icon - <?php the_title();?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Post Object instead.

When in the loop, do this:

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_name;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it works to use just `echo $post->post_name;`, like this: `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_img/icon_page-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>.png" alt="Icon - <?php the_title();?>" />`